# объявление namespace и класса в заголовочном файле

Tags: c++

есть 3 файла
2 cpp
и один заголовочный
вот часть кода из cpp с классом и namespace

```
namespace textrs {
    enum texNumber {
        FIRST,
        SECOND,
    };
}

class gameObject {
//некий код
}
```

а вот код из заголовочного файла

```
#pragma once
#ifndef helplib
#define helplib
namespace textrs { enum texNumber {}; };
class gameObject {};
#endif
```

я не особо разбираюсь с заголовочными файлами и поэтому не знаю как исправить.

Comment: Нужно в заголовочном сделать предварительное объявление (forward declaration) класса (внутри namespace). Перечисление оставьте только в заголовочном, оно по умолчанию inline. В файле реализации можно вместо помещения метода в namespace указать через разрешение контекста: `ns::MyClass::MyClass() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

объявления, к которым вы будете обращаться  нужны только в заголовочном файле, если объявлять еще и в cpp будет конфликт имён

```
// example.h

#pragma once
#ifndef helplib
#define helplib

namespace textrs 
{ 
  enum texNumber {}; 
};

class gameObject {};

#endif
```

в файл cpp нужно включить заголовочный файл чтобы ему были видны необходимые объявления

```
// example.cpp

#include "example.h"
```

Comment: Кто-то постоянно минусует нормальные ответы.

Comment: А зачем `#pragma once` и include guards одновременно?

Comment: @dIm0n их можно использовать вместе для переносимости, и где `#pragma once` поддерживается дает некоторые оптимизации скорости компиляции

Comment: @Ildar почему для переносимости? include guards везде поддерживаются и так

Comment: @dIm0n `#pragma once` не везде, а его применение дает оптимизации времени компиляции, в моей сборке стандартной библиотеки обе защиты применяются в хедерах

Comment: @dIm0n https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090382/why-using-both-pragma-once-and-include-guard вот что нашел, не могу сказать следует ли писать так или нет, это на рассмотрении программистов

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению я пока не могу оставлять коментарии, поэтому немного перефразирую коллегу в отдельном ответе:
Для обращения к объявленным в заголовочном файле (*.h) элементам, необходимо подключить его в нужном *.срр файле.

Comment: Уже можете комментировать :)